# Remove all white space in a file and replace them with a comma using Vim

Tags: vim

Anyone has an idea how to remove all white space and replace them  with a comma `,` in a file using Vim ?
File input  example (words could be everywhere !):

```
C1       TEST   PROD
A1    BE


T1     B1
```

File output example(all words belonging to the same line are like in the example below):

```
C1,TEST,PROD
A1,BE
T1,B1
```

**I Found it** :
`%s/\s\{1,}/,/gc`

Answer (score 82, accepted):

First delete the blank lines:

```
:g/^\s*$/d
```

Then use a substitution (`:s///`) over each line (`%`) to replace all (`g`) continuous whitespace  (`\s\+`) with a comma (`,`).

```
 :%s/\s\+/,/g
```

Comment: Explanations of each component is particularly helpful and often omitted in answers on SO. Thanks! (That said, the same for the first line would also be helpful)

Comment: Very useful to generate a `*.csv` file.

Answer (score 6):

Another way to do it :

`%s/\s\{1,}/,/gc`

Answer (score 0):

when converting a text file with headers and text fields with spaces I used `%s/\s\{2,}/,/g`

Answer (score 0):

If the file contains n number of line and contains spaces at the start of each line, end of each line and in between. And you want to remove spaces at start and end and replace in between multiple spaces with a comma ",". And also redirect the output and save to a new file keeping the original file as it is.

Use the following command -

```
sed -e 's/^[ \t]*// ; s/[[:blank:]]*$// ; s/\s\+/,/g ; s/,$//' input-file-name | tee output-file-name
```

give paths of the input file name if not in the same directory.

or you can write all these -

```
"s/^[ \t]*//
s/[[:blank:]]*$//
s/\s\+/,/g ; s/,$//"
```

in a txt file save it. and use -f option.

so the command becomes -

```
sed -f commands.txt input-file-name.txt | tee output-file-name.txt
```

commnads.txt contains the above conditions of sed command